# Probability of final observation in sample of past independent events occurring as such to bring sample probability in line with expected probability

Tags: probability, statistics

And sorry for the sloppy vocab usage above and I'm sure to follow. I know very little about statistics, but this problem is literally keeping me awake right now trying to work through it.

I think this can be applied to any distribution with an expected parameter, but I will use coin flips as that is what I am stuck on. If I have a set of 100 previously recorded coin flips, then I know that the expected probability of the next toss (n=101) being heads is p = 0.5. However, if I were to randomly select from my record of 100 flips a set of 10 consecutive flips, it seems to me I should expect ex ante that the distribution of flips in that set should reflect p(H) = 0.5; p(T) = 0.5 as well. If I know the first 9 observations in that set give me observations of 5 tails and 4 heads, what is the probability that the final 10th observation is heads?

As stated before, I know a new flip - unbound from being included in any subset - will have the expected probability of a coin flip. But since I should expect 5 tails and 5 heads in my subset, it seems the probability of the final observation being heads should be p(H₁₀) > 0.5 in order to satisfy that expectation. At the same time I know it can't be 100% either. Please help.

Comment: Any new throw doesn't depend on the past - throws are independent - regardless of how you slice the subsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common misconception when looking at probabilities and statistical data. See, when you said that half the flips of the recorded data should be heads and the other half should be tails is partially incorrect. The correct way to think about it is  to say that $\frac{the\;number\; of\; heads}{the\; number\; of\; tails}$ approaches
$1$ as the number of flips approach infinity. So applying this to any finite number of flips doesn't give you a complete accurate result, only a probabilistic one that approaches the correct result as the number of flips goes up

Comment: I see. That also helps answer another permutation of the situation I was considering where of the set of 10, I find I have 7 tails and 2 heads.  My framework just broke down at that point as it became impossible to match expected distribution.

To be clear though. Is the probability of that final 10th flip in my original post p(H) = 0.5? Or is there some formula that takes into account the number of occurrences in the set such that it may be different with smaller sample sizes yet approaches 0.5 as the set size increases to infinity?

Comment: No no, you were right when you said that the 10th flip should have a probability of 0.5 or 50%. In a situation like this past probabilistic results don't affect future events and future probabilities. So the chance of the 10th flip being heads is 50%